# Any add-on(service) for firefox to compress incoming data like opera

Tags: firefox, compression, opera

I want to know if there is any service or add-on available for firefox to compress the incoming data like opera browser.

Comment: Visit [How do I use the Google data compression proxy on Firefox?](http://superuser.com/q/945924/328353)

Comment: Ans: Now [Google DataSaver proxy for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google_datasaver_for_firefox/) is available.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [fasTun Tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fastun-tool/)?

> fasTun Tool provides a convenient interface to quickly activate and deactivate fasTun (free Web Accelerator service with HTTP compression), built-authentication, load the original images bypassing fasTun and quick access to service's settings.

Comment: That's a dead link. Also, in the comments [of a related plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fastun-tool/) someone wrote in June 2014: "This app no longer works and the website for the app has been down for months".

Answer (score 0):

[Janus Proxy Configurator](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Janus-Proxy-Configurator_71802177.html)

click "**Manuelle Instalation**"! sometimes it can crash the server or not load page.

Comment: Do you use it? On https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Janus I read "The Janus proxy experiment has ended".

Answer (score -1):

Short: There isn't any.

---

Long: Opera's Turbo works by sending the request to Opera's webservers, which get the data in uncompressed format, [even if the webserver sends the data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36566/sofu-rejecting-requests-coming-from-opera-if-turbo-mode-is-on) in compressed manner( eg: Stack Exchange sites), compress these and send it back to the browser. Theoretically, it's possible to simulate this via an addon but it's trivial for Opera to block these, and it wouldn't look good.

Perhaps something which you can roll out yourself if you're so inclined

Comment: @Sathya i have just found one. Take a look http://fastun.com

Comment: looks like it is working. pages are loading a bit faster

Comment: but free account comes with limited usages.

Comment: @kaykay you should post that as an answer then

Comment: @Sathya is it good to post the ans of my own question. because i can wait if anybody know a better solution than this.

Comment: @Kaykay posting your own answer is not frowned upon, you're free to wait for an answer from someone else or answer on your own