# How to reduce website bandwidth usage on Firefox PC using 4G/LTE

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

In Firefox 73+, how to reduce bandwidth usage?

Some websites take up to 5Mb of bandwidth just to load the main page.

I'm already using uMatrix and uBlock Origin addons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will cache a lot of what needs to be loaded so the transferred size is much less than the total size. For further savings, you can try additional addons.

If you're browsing websites where you just need text, [Textise-it](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/textise-it/) is good for that.

I also came across two data saving addons:

[Save-Data: on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-data/)

> Automatically enable data-savings mode at compatible websites.

[Bandwidth Hero](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bandwidth-hero/)

> Saves data by compressing images on the page.
>   Bandwidth Hero saves data by compressing all images on the page via data compression service which reduces image size by about 50%-75%.

I haven't used them but you can read the reviews or look into them for yourself.

Comment: Bandwidth Hero is no longer mantained. It needs a server to pack the contents. `Save-Date: On` seems to help a little. I think there is not one solution for this case. It is a pack of measures and addons like adblocks etc...

Comment: Ah I see, that's unfortunate. Yeah hopefully more people will be able to provide insight on other methods. I found this post, not sure how relevant it is now but maybe worth looking into: https://superuser.com/questions/945924/how-do-i-use-the-google-data-compression-proxy-on-firefox